# Mysql insert data from one table to another selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I have a Mysql db with 2 tables 
first table has 2 fields

`country_code` and `city_name`

second table has 3 fields

`country_code`, `country_name`, `country_cities`

I need to create a query that:

`select all city_name and country_code from first table and for each country_code insert into second table in field country_cities`

The cities found on first table separated by commas

I am not sure if I can do it with a Mysql query or is better use a php script
thanks for help

Comment: do you want comma separated values in city for second table?

Comment: but is the second table already popolated with country_code and country_name ?

Comment: what you mean by `The cities found on first table separated by commas`?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the city_name column in the second table with the list of city's from the first table. If the first table's city name is already comma seperated, you just move it from one table to the other.

```
UPDATE second_table 
SET S.country_cities = A.city_name
FROM first table A INNER JOIN second_table S 
ON A.country_code = S.country_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update `country_cities` in `second_table`, you can do that by this example query:

```
UPDATE second_table st
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    country_code,
    GROUP_CONCAT(city_name) as grouped_cities
    FROM first_table
    GROUP BY country_code
) as tmp_table ON tmp_table.country_code = st.country_code
SET st.country_cities = tmp_table.grouped_cities;
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can find GROUP_CONCAT documentation.
Just a copy&past of it, to avoid confusion about separators:

> The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”). To
>   specify a separator explicitly, use SEPARATOR followed by the string
>   literal value that should be inserted between group values. To
>   eliminate the separator altogether, specify SEPARATOR ''.

Comment: thanks Giulio it works but it does not insert all city_name in country_cities of second table but only a subset cannot understand why

Comment: Probably because the second_table contains only a subset of country_code